Logging subclass is not retrieved correctly
I am using python's logging library and I need to create a custom logger that logs two attributes of my process: instance_name and instance_id. I have come to this solution that works successfully, though I'm not sure if it overlooks something/does something unnecessary:
import logging
from logging import Formatter

class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name, extra={}):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.extra = extra

    def _log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info=None, extra=None, stack_info=False, **kwargs):
        if extra is None:
            extra = self.extra
        else:
            extra.update(self.extra)
        super()._log(level, msg, args, exc_info, extra, stack_info, **kwargs)

logger = CustomLogger("test-logger", {"instance_name": "name", "instance_id": 12})
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - instance name: %(instance_name)s - instance id: %(instance_id)i - %(message)s"
)
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)

if I use this logger to log a message, I get what I expect
logger.info("Hello world")
# 2024-11-14 16:22:51,320 - INFO - name: name - id: 12 - Hello world

But if I want to retrieve that same logger later in the code, it does not contain any handler and therefore won't log anything
logging.setLoggerClass(CustomLogger)
retrieved_logger = logging.getLogger("test-logger")

# doesn't print anything
retrieved_logger.info("Hello world")

logger.handlers, retrieved_logger.handlers
# ([<StreamHandler stderr (NOTSET)>], [])

I also know that the retrieved logger is a singleton and it must be the same instance as logger
logger is retrieved_logger
# False

My question is: where is the problem here? Why can't I get the same logger I configured?

The logging framework doesn't know about the logger you created before setting the logger class. You aren't supposed to instantiate loggers yourself, but to let the logging framework do so when you request a logger by name using getLogger.

@chepner not sure what you mean by this. Can you elaborate on what I should do instead? I am just creating a logger in my code and then retrieving it somewhere else with getLogger

Use setLoggerClass first, then call logging.getLogger.

Isn't that what I am doing in the third block of code though?

You said "later in the code"; I assume you are doing that in addition to instantiating the custom logger, rather than instead of.

I would kindly invite you to elaborate a bit more your explanations, ideally in the form of an answer. If you take my code as I posted it (copying the blocks one below the others) and run it, there's an expected outcome (the variable retrieved_logger should contain handlers) and that does not happen, even when I did everything I thought it was necessary (for example, setting the logger class). i think you can follow the steps that don't work for me, but I'm happy to provide any additional clarification you need regarding it.

You can use neologger library, it gives you the customisation you need.
You can find the detailed examples here:
NeoLogger: A Developer’s Solution to Effortless, Beautiful Logging for Python Apps
Also, the pip project's homepage:
neologger
Hope it helps.

Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I have to stick to plain logging
